# Remove Category filter from Shop By Filter Renderer in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, layered-navigation

Our designer has made a layout that was supposed to be based on the default theme, however me made one diversion with categories and designed something more akin to what we did once in Magento 1. I need to display a custom block in the sidebar with category links and a current category selection. This is all fine and easy enough for me to do with one problem, I need to remove the default category option form the layered navigation filter.

I've been looking through the XML for a way to remove specific filters from the layered navigation with no luck. I've also tried looking through the renderer class, implementation and filter interface but I can't find any way to stop categories from coming out under the layered navigation.

**TLDR I need to remove Categories from the layered navigation but keep all the other filters**